# Cohen forcing reals generate whole extension?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I have a doubt about the reals that Cohen forcing adds to ground model.

If $\{c_i\}_{i\in I}$ are Cohen reals then $M[G]=M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]$ ?

where $G$ is a generic filter for Cohen forcing.

My attemp. each $p\in G$ is a partial function with domain in $[I\times\omega]^{<\omega}$. Then, if $\pi_1(dom(p))=\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$ we have $p=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}(c_{i_j}\upharpoonright dom(p))\in M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]$. So, $G\in M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]$. I'm right?.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the many proofs that in the case of the Cohen reals, the reals determine the generic filter?

Comment: And what is your doubt? Saying you have a doubt doesn't help us answer your question. Explaining your doubt would.

Comment: What is $I$ in this context?

Comment: What is $M[ \{c_i \}_{i \in I} ]$ anyways, if not a forcing extension? I suppose it's meant to be the $\subseteq$-minimal transitive model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ $N$ such that $M \cup \{ c_i \mid i \in I \} \subseteq N$. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @StefanMesken Yes is the minimal transitive models.

Comment: @Gödel In that case you only need to show how to compute $G$ from $\{c_i \mid i \in I \}$. Can you do it for a single Cohen real?

Comment: @AsafKaragila how can i prove it? i don't know how beginning. I have that $M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]\subseteq M[G]$ (is trivial), but, in the other direction?

Comment: Think about *what* is the objects that are in $G$, and how to define them from the Cohen reals. It would be help to start with the case that $I$ is a singleton, so you want to show that $G\in M[c]$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  My attemp. We have that each $p\in G$ is a partial function with domain in $[I\times\omega]$. Then, if $\pi_1(dom(p))=\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$ we have $p=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}c_{i_j}\upharpoonright\pi_1(dom(p))\in M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]$ (where $\pi_1$ is the canonical projection in the first component). So, $G\in M[\{c_i\}_{i\in I}]$. I'm right?

Comment: Use the [edit].

Comment: @AsafKaragila edit?

Comment: It's a link. Try clicking it.